# WordPress Multisite. Can domain be used instead of subdomain?

Tags: multisite, domain, subdomains

i am new to multisite. It is a simple question. I know WordPress multisite can be setup for subdomains. Is it possible to use domains along with subdomains? I have searched google but have not had really good results. Perhaps I have used the wrong keywords.

**so i can use a single wordpress installation for:**

domain.com

sub1.domain.com

sub2.domain.com

example.com

example2.com

sub1.example2com

Hope you get it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"example2.com

sub1.example2com"

Actually for subsites off of mapped sites, you want a multi network plugin.

Free - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-multi-network/

Paid - http://wpebooks.com/networks/

Comment: Thanks! One more thing. Can you recommend me any hosting provider that is good with wordpress multisite? I want to start with a shared hosting first. Then if necessary will upgrade. I am thinking about hostgator. But want to discuss it with with experienced people. I was created a post here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-your-recommendation-of-host-for-wp-multisite?replies=2 but closed by mods. Thanks!

Comment: HostGator is good for multisite. Avoid WebHostingPad at all costs.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. Follow this http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/